# resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings and error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-instant-apps

I got an error as below recently on the Instant App compilation

`[2018-09-24T04:42:32Z] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[2018-09-24T04:42:32Z]
[2018-09-24T04:42:32Z] * What went wrong:
[2018-09-24T04:42:32Z] Execution failed for task ':base-feature:processProductionReleaseFeatureResources'.
[2018-09-24T04:42:32Z] > Android resource linking failed
[2018-09-24T04:42:32Z]   Output:  /project/base-feature/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeProductionReleaseFeatureResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:630: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
[2018-09-24T04:42:32Z]   /project/base-feature/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeProductionReleaseFeatureResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:631: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
[2018-09-24T04:42:32Z]   error: failed linking references.`

It was all the while compile good, and nothing change. Then suddenly the compile now fail with this. What could cause this issue, and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue is due to butterknife 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I have filed as issue in https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1371